# Video streaming in Flash

Tags: flash

I am using Flash CS4 to develop a web page based on Flash. I have a requirement to show videos within the Flash page. The videos can be of type .swf, .wmv. Does Flash has capability to include another .SWF or .WMV file as embedded video viewer. Appreciate any thoughts.

Addition:
If I have .fla file, can I embed .flv file inside .fla file so that a video can be played within .fla (binary .swf) file?

Answer (score 0):

SWF is not a video format, it is the flash binary file, so it can be read by flash and can load another swf.

WMV is the Window Media Video developed by Microsoft and can not be embedded within flash.

So in flash you can read the video with the format of FLV (codec sorenson spark, on2 vp6) or MP4 (codec H264).